# Drag'n drop. Как сказать мыши что обект нужно отпустить? На примере готового кода

Tags: javascript, mouse-event, mousemove

Есть небольшая тестовая страница с полем и кругом, который должен перемещаться по этому полю. Задача в целом решена, если раскомментировать те участки кода, который закоментированы в примере ниже. Но почему это работает я пока логически не могу понять, поэтому ищу другие способы. Подскажите что можно добавить в код, чтобы сообщить объекту что мышь его отпустила и нужно перестать следовать за курсором?

Также подскажите как сделать так чтобы круг двигался ТОЛЬКО в пределах поля, а не по всему окну.

```js
let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
let moveMoving = false;

circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  // moveMoving = true;
  let locationX = event.pageX - circle.style.left - 20;
  let locationY = event.pageY - circle.style.top - 20;
  moveCircle(event)

  function moveCircle(event) {
    circle.style.left = event.clientX - locationX + 'px';
    circle.style.top = event.clientY - locationY + 'px';
  }

  circle.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    // if (!moveMoving) return;
    moveCircle(event);

  });

  circle.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    // moveMoving = false;

  });

});
```

```css
.parallelepiped {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(195, 0, 255);
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(23, 235, 4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parallelepiped'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

P.S. `circle.style.left - 20;` В данном случае я отнимаю 20 пикселей отступа чтобы круг не прыгал в правый левый угол, когда на него нажимают мышью. решение не самое изящное, но пока так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите что можно добавить в код, чтобы сообщить объекту что мышь его отпустила и нужно перестать следовать за курсором?

Необходимо отписаться от события, то есть использовать removeEventListener на той же функции, которую добавляли ранее.

> Также подскажите как сделать так чтобы круг двигался ТОЛЬКО в пределах поля, а не по всему окну.

При перемещении сравнивать получившиеся координаты с размерами параллелепипеда. Обратите внимание на свойство "position: relative" у параллелепипеда. Из-за него круг перемещается относительно параллелепипеда, а не всего документа

> Но почему это работает я пока логически не могу понять

Если переменная moveMoving равна true, перемещение круга просто блокируется:

```
if (!moveMoving) return;
```

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
const parallelepiped = document.querySelector('.parallelepiped');
let locationX = 0;
let locationY = 0;

  function moveCircle(event) {
    let left = event.clientX - locationX;
    let top = event.clientY - locationY;
    if(left < 0){
      // выходит за границу параллелепипеда слева, останавливаем
      left = 0;
    }
    if(left > parallelepiped.scrollWidth - circle.scrollWidth){
      // выходит за границу параллелепипеда справа, останавливаем
      left = parallelepiped.scrollWidth - circle.scrollWidth;
    }
    circle.style.left = left + 'px';
    // с top нужно сделать аналогично
    circle.style.top = top + 'px';
  }

circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if(circle.style.left){
     locationX = event.pageX - circle.style.left.replace('px', '');
  }else{
     locationX = event.pageX - 20;
  }
  if(circle.style.top){
     locationY = event.pageY - circle.style.top.replace('px', '');
  }else{
     locationY = event.pageY - 20;
  }
  moveCircle(event)
  // добавляем отслеживание события перемещения
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCircle);
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  // убираем отслеживание события перемещения
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveCircle);
});
```

```css
.parallelepiped {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(195, 0, 255);
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(23, 235, 4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parallelepiped'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли особенно по условиям. Ниже написал ответом новый код, подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить?

Comment: @Alius999, когда вы привязываете события к кругу, это означает, что события будут срабатывать только в тот момент, когда курсор находится над кругом. Поэтому я привязываю события к document

Answer (score 0):

Сделал немного по своему. Ниже код.

Осталось решить одну задачу - когда водишь мышкой чуть быстрее то круг как будто "не успевает" за курсором и оцепляется. Подскажите как это можно устранить?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='parallelepiped'>
        <div class='circle'></div>
    </div>
    <script>

        let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
        let parallelepiped = document.querySelector('.parallelepiped');
        let moveMoving = false;

        circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
            moveMoving = true;
            let locationX = event.pageX - circle.style.left - 20;
            let locationY = event.pageY - circle.style.top - 20;

            moveCircle(event)
            
            
            function moveCircle(event) {

                let overflowWidth = event.clientX - locationX;
                let overflowHeight = event.clientY - locationY;

                if (overflowWidth < 0) {
                    circle.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    overflowWidth = parallelepiped.scrollWidth;
                }

                if (overflowHeight < 0) {
                    circle.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    overflowHeight = parallelepiped.scrollHeight;
                }

                if (overflowWidth > parallelepiped.scrollWidth - circle.scrollWidth) {
                    circle.style.left = parallelepiped.scrollWidth;
                    moveMoving = false;
                } else {
                circle.style.left = event.clientX - locationX + 'px';
                
            }
                if (overflowHeight > parallelepiped.scrollHeight - circle.scrollHeight) {
                    circle.style.top = parallelepiped.scrollHeight;
                    moveMoving = false;
                } else {
                    circle.style.top = event.clientY - locationY + 'px';
                }
            }

            circle.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
                if (!moveMoving) return;
                moveCircle(event);
                
            });

            circle.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
                moveMoving = false;
                
            });            

        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS код тот же:

```
.parallelepiped {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: rgb(195, 0, 255);
}

.circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(23, 235, 4); 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Зря вы объявляете mousemove и mouseup внутри mousedown. При каждом нажатии мыши на круг будут создаваться новые слушатели событий (но старые не исчезнут, ведь вы не использовали removeEventListener), что приведет к излишнему потреблению памяти. Добавьте console.log в mouseup и переместите круг несколько раз - сообщения в консоли начнут двоиться, троиться и так далее